# how to change colour of text after reading details?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

am doing my projects using iphone, where i list a number of events in `uitableview`(masterview) and i will display details in `viewController`(detailview). i display a text in tableview as green colour, after reading details a data inside a cell should turn red colur. to notify it as read and unread. how to do it? pls help me. here is my cellforrowindexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newsCell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
        MainNews *msglist = [samplearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = msglist.newsletters;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
}
```

and here is my didselectatrowindexpath code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MainNewsDetailController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        MainNews *aEvent1 = [samplearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.eveID = aEvent1.id;
        destViewController.usrid = memberid;

    }
}
```

so how to change colour in tableview after reading details . pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: tell me how iphone will detect wether you read any line or not? do you think it's possible automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can have bool property something like `isRead` in your `MainNews` model class.  And once the particular news is selected to read, set the property isRead = YES. Then inside  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` datasource method check for the property to set the text color.

Your code might look like this

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    MainNews *msglist = [samplearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(msglist.isRead)
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    else
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

and inside your prepareForSegue

```
    MainNewsDetailController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    MainNews *aEvent1 = [samplearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    aEvent1.isRead = YES;
```

**Please Note:** This answer only checks whether the user tapped the particular news but not whether he has read or not.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how will you detect that whether user has read the text or not...
but you can definitely change the color of particular cell as below.

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
[[yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndex].textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

**Hope this will help you.**